# Handlebars: How pass @index as parameter to custom helper

Tags: javascript, php, handlebars.js

**Setup:**

- I'm using [Handelbars.PHP](https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php), but maybe a solution with Handlebars.js in mind can help me.
- A custom helper `content` that expects two parameters a collection and an index.
- An `#each` helper invocation that calls to `#content` helper, like this:

  {{#each data}}
       {{#content ../parent_options @index}}{{/content}}
  {{/each}}

**The issue:**

Inside the `content` helper definition I want to access the `@index` value, say `0,1,2,...` but I'm only getting a string!

How can pass as a parameter and access inside the content helper definition the value of `@index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everplays [commented](https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php/issues/27#issuecomment-27639972) and [boukeversteegh](https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php/issues/27#issuecomment-27643054) commented in the [official project repo](https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php):

> `Handlebars.PHP` doesn't parse arguments of helpers, it's your job to
>   parse and give meaning to them (I'm talking about third parameter that
>   gets passed to helpers, `_helper_each($template, $context, $args,
>   $source))`. But in your case, there's no need to parse arguments, you
>   can simply access it by `$context->lastIndex()`.

Full comments at https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php/issues/27

**Final custom helper for reference:**

```
    /**
     * Handlebars Helper Content. Return object->Alphabet[index].
     *
     * @param $template
     * @param $context
     * @param $args
     * @param $source
     *
     * @return Handlebars_String
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public static function _helper_content($template, $context, $args, $source) {
        $Alphabet = range('A', 'Z');

        $tmp = explode(' ', $args);
        $buffer = '';

        $object = $context->get($tmp[0]);

        if (count($tmp) < 2 || $tmp[1] == '@index') {
            $last_index = $context->lastIndex();
            $letter = $Alphabet[$last_index];
        }
        else {
            $index = $context->get($tmp[1]);
            $letter = $Alphabet[$index];
        }

        $buffer .= $object->$letter;

        return new Handlebars_String($buffer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Herebelow is some boilerplate code you can use to create powerful templates with custom helpers, while still using but a minimal amount of code.

It contains two helpers :

- One to change a string to uppercase. A `@key` value is passed to it in the demo code.
- One to increment a numeric value. An `@index` value is passed to it in the demo code.

### Template `table.hbs` :

```
{{#if table}}
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 2%;">#</th>
            {{#each table.0}}
            <th nowrap="nowrap">
                {{uppercase @key}}
            </th>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each table}}
        <tr> 
            <th>{{increment @index}}</th>
            {{#each this}}
            <td><input type="text" value="{{this}}" /></td>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
{{#if paginator}}
<nav class="pagination">
    <ul>
        {{#each paginator}}
        <li><a href="{{this}}">{{@key}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</nav>
{{/if}}
{{else}}
<p>No data found!</p>
{{/if}}
```

### The view :

```
// Create handlebars object
$template_engine = new \Handlebars\Handlebars;

// Get helpers object
$helpers = $template_engine->getHelpers();

// Add 'camelize' helper
$helpers->add('uppercase', function($template, $context, $args, $source) {
    return ucwords($context->get($args));
});

// Add 'increment' helper
$helpers->add('increment', function($template, $context, $args, $source) {
    return $context->get($args) + 1;
});

// Render template
echo $template_engine->render(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/table.hbs'), array(
    'table' => array(
        array('name' => 'John', 'profession' => 'programmer', 'city' => 'Leuven'),
        array('name' => 'Sam', 'profession' => 'designer', 'city' => 'Aarschot'),
        array('name' => 'Tom', 'profession' => 'owner', 'city' => 'Leuven'),
        array('name' => 'Steve', 'profession' => 'copywriter', 'city' => 'Brussels'),
        array('name' => 'Thomas', 'profession' => 'designer', 'city' => 'Antwerp')
    ),
    'paginator' => array(
        'first' => 'http://www.test.com/first',
        '1' => 'http://www.test.com/1',
        '2' => 'http://www.test.com/2',
        '3' => 'http://www.test.com/3',
        'last' => 'http://www.test.com/last'
    )
));
```

### The output :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 2%;">#</th>
            <th nowrap="nowrap">
                Name
            </th>
            <th nowrap="nowrap">
                Profession
            </th>
            <th nowrap="nowrap">
                City
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td><input type="text" value="John" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="programmer" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="Leuven" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td><input type="text" value="Sam" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="designer" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="Aarschot" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>3</th>
            <td><input type="text" value="Tom" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="owner" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="Leuven" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <td><input type="text" value="Steve" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="copywriter" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="Brussels" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>5</th>
            <td><input type="text" value="Thomas" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="designer" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="Antwerp" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<nav class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.test.com/first">first</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.test.com/1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.test.com/2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.test.com/3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.test.com/last">last</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```